# Amazon MWS submitting price setting feed

Tags: php, xml, api, amazon-mws

I've been looking at the documentation scratching my head wondering how to submit an XML feed which would do something as simple as changing the price of an inventory item

I've been looking at the example XML feed that they give as shown on page 15 in this [link](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V146551159_.pdf), since this is the only example I have found I don't know how to go about inserting or editing products in my sellers inventory. How can it be done?

**example given**

```
POST /?Marketplace=ATVExampleDER
  & Action=SubmitFeed
  &Merchant=A1XExample5E6
  &FeedType=_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_
  &AWSAccessKeyId=0PB842ExampleN4ZTR2
  &Version=2009-01-01
  &Signature=SvSExamplefZpSignaturex2cs%3D
  &SignatureVersion=2
  &SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
  &Timestamp=2009-01-26T23%3A51%3A31.315Z HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-MD5: ExampleMd5HashOfHttpBodyAsPerRfc2616Example
User-Agent: MWSTestsuite/2009-03-05 (Language=Java/1.6.0_11/50.0/
Sun Microsystems Inc.; Platform=Linux/i386/2.4.21-50a6smp;
MWSClientVersion=2009-03-09)
Host: mws.amazonservices.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**FeedContent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_EXAMPLE_123456</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>56789</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
          <Type>ASIN</Type>
          <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
        <DescriptionData>
          <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
          <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
          <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
          <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
          <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
          <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
          <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
          <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
          <Health>
           <ProductType>
              <HealthMisc>
                <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
              </HealthMisc>
            </ProductType>
          </Health>
        </ProductData>
    </Product>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [Guide to XML.](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V158772716_.pdf)  It gives a better picture of the steps needed to list a product on Amazon.

You will basically be submitting a Product feed first, which gives all of the general information about the product and creates a partial listing in your inventory.  Then post an Inventory feed, which will set the quantity you have available.  Finally, a price feed, which sets the price.  After doing this once for a product, you only need to upload the quantity or price feed, depending on which one needs to be changed.

Comment: good explanation. I want to know that supposes product already selling in amazon and I want also sell that product then I also need to send same AmazonEnvelope xml ? and pass ASIN in value  <StandardProductID>          <Type>ASIN</Type> <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value> </StandardProductID> ? and what If product not exists in amazon ?